# Android multiple searchview's one layout has alignment issues, how do I get the listview

Tags: android, android-layout, android-xml, searchview

I have two SearchViews in a screen, when the list for the SearchView with id search_to expands it lines up under the search_from SearchView. The layout looks like this

```
  <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <android.support.v7.widget.SearchView
            android:id="@+id/search_from"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="bottom"
            app:dividerPadding="0dp"
            app:iconifiedByDefault="false"
            app:queryHint="From"
            app:searchIcon="@drawable/a_circle" />


        <android.support.v7.widget.SearchView
            android:id="@+id/search_to"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:layout_below="@+id/search_from"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="bottom"
            app:dividerPadding="0dp"
            app:iconifiedByDefault="false"
            app:queryHint="To"
            app:searchIcon="@drawable/b_circle" />

    </LinearLayout>
```

At first I tried putting them in a vertical linear layout but when the list expands for the second searchview it would cover up the entire searchview widget completely. I figured if I can find the id of the actual list that shows up I can change the layout params and arrange it how I want but when I took an xml snapshot I can't see it anywhere in the layout.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this problem.  I can't remember the specifics, but it was something weird like the `SearchView` holding a `static` reference to the drop down view.  I finally gave up and used an `AutoCompleteTextView` in place of one of the `SearchView`s.